# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING)

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo un envio de correos con php y me da el siguiente error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING)

este es mi codigo:

```
$cuerpo = "<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030"><title>MAPFRE ATLAS</title></head><body>".$xMail."</body></html>\r\n";
```

Comment: Te faltan lo escapes de caracteres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un problema de uso de comillas simples y dobles, básicamente estas usando el mismo tipo para:

- Declarar el contenido de la variable
- Declarar el contenido de los atributos de las *meta* tags

Entonces tendrías que hacer el cambio y colocar el valor de cada uno de los atributos como comillas simples

Algo así:

```
$cuerpo = "<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html'; charset='gb18030'><title>MAPFRE ATLAS</title></head><body>".$xMail."</body></html>\r\n";

echo $cuerpo;
```

Comment: O *escapar* caracteres como ya te recomiendan